# Ordering rows with datatables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Surely this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to turn up any code that works for me. I'm working with a DataTable in R Shiny. I want to generate the DataTable and have it ordered by default on the second column rather than the first. This is what I have in server.R:

```
output$TabVals <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(TableData(), 
              options = list(pageLength = 25, 
                             searching = FALSE, 
                             paging = FALSE),   
              rownames = FALSE) %>%
      formatRound(2, digits = 0)
})
```

This works great. What I found other people had done was include in the options `order = list(2, 'asc')` (since I'm sorting on the second column and want the data ascending. When I add that line, however, the DataTable no longer displays any rows.

I put together this example to recreate the problem:

```
c1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
c2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
test <- cbind(c1, c2)

test1 <-  DT::datatable(test)
test2 <-  DT::datatable(test, options = list(order = list(2, 'desc')))
```

`test1` makes a nice DataTable. `test2` generates a blank table.

I tried moving the `order = list(2, 'asc')` to other parts of the code (eg after options, before rownames, after the pipe), but that didn't help. Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`DT` is based on javascript, so the indexing starts at 0 instead of 1.
That's why your table is blank, you want to sort for a non-existent column.

So this should work:

```
c1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
c2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
test <- cbind(c1, c2)

test1 <-  DT::datatable(test)
test2 <-  DT::datatable(test, options = list(order = list(1, 'desc')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure this is what you are after, but you could try either of the following

```
library(data.table). 
c1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
c2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
test <- data.table(c1,c2)
setkey(test,c2)
test
# or
test[, some function in j, by = c2]
```

Hope that helps.  I have a hunch you know more R than I.

Comment: It's possible that there's a way to apply these solutions, but my attempts to format them so that they're compatible with the `datatable()` call have come up short. I'm stuck using that function because I'm working within the confines of Shiny and therefore also within the confines of the `renderDataTable({})` function.

Comment: Clare's Q is about the `DT` package which wraps the JavaScript library `DataTables` and not about the `data.table` package which extends data.frames. Unfortunately, the names look very similar.